# Variadic template with type checks

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates

I have some opencl kernel wrapper objects which take arguments, currently I run them like this:

```
kernel.setArg<0>(count);
kernel.setArg<1>(data);
```

But it would be a lot cleaner if I could run it like this:

```
kernel.setArgs(count, data);
```

I want this type safe, since the arguments can only be of either `int` or `buffer&`.

My first thought was variadic templates and I got it working, but without type safety:

```
#include <iostream>

struct buffer {};
class kernel {
    template<int arg, int numArg, typename T>
    void setArgs_(T& data) {
        setKernelArg<numArg>(data);
    }
    template<int arg, int numArg, typename T, typename... Args>
    void setArgs_(T& data, Args&&... params) {
        setKernelArg<arg>(data);
        setArgs_<arg+1, numArg, Args...>(params...);
    }
    template<int argNum>
    void setKernelArg(buffer& data) {
        std::cout <<"setting arg " << argNum << " to buffer" << std::endl;
        //set arg argNum to data, long function
    }
    template<int argNum>
    void setKernelArg(int data) {
        std::cout <<"setting arg " << argNum << " to int" << std::endl;
        //set arg argNum to data, long function
    }
public:
    template<typename T, typename... Args>
    void setArgs(T& data, Args&&... params) {
        setArgs_<0, sizeof...(params), T, Args...>(data, params...);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    buffer a,b,c;
    int i,j,k;
    kernel kern;
    kern.setArgs(a,i,b,j,c,k);
    return 0;
}
```

The only types that should be supported, at compile time, are `int` and `buffer&`, but I can't get it working like I want. I tried `std::enable_if`:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, buffer&>::value> setArgs(T& data, Args&&... params) {
    setArgs_<0, sizeof...(params), buffer&, Args...>(data, params...);
}
template<typename T, typename... Args>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, int>::value> setArgs(T& data, Args&&... params) {
    setArgs_<0, sizeof...(params), int, Args...>(data, params...);
}
```

but then I get

```
varargs_typesafe.cpp:41:29: error: call of overloaded ‘setArgs(buffer&, int&, buffer&, int&, buffer&, int&)’ is ambiguous
 kern.setArgs(a,i,b,j,c,k);
                         ^
varargs_typesafe.cpp:28:62: note: candidate: std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, buffer&>::value> kernel::setArgs(T&, Args&& ...) [with T = buffer; Args = {int&, buffer&, int&, buffer&, int&}]
     typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, buffer&>::value> setArgs(T& data, Args&&... params) {
                                                              ^
varargs_typesafe.cpp:32:58: note: candidate: std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, int>::value> kernel::setArgs(T&, Args&& ...) [with T = buffer; Args = {int&, buffer&, int&, buffer&, int&}]
     typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, int>::value> setArgs(T& data, Args&&... params) {
```

Feels like my `std::enable_if` isn't working properly or I'm missing something.

EDIT:
I tried this by giving my working code giving it a `bool` as argument and it works, but a `std::string` fails. Is this because a `bool` can be converted to an `int`? Can I disallow such casts somehow?

Comment: Could you use C++14 / 17?

Comment: 14 should be doable, 17 might be trickier.

Comment: Are all your `int` going to be passed by reference? Changing `setKernelArg` to take `int&` would immediately make it stop accepting booleans.

Comment: @kennytm It works, thanks! So there's no implicit conversion to references? That's good to know.

Comment: It is unsound to pass a `bool&` to an `int& foo` because if someone writes `foo = 2` the original boolean will become invalid.

Comment: Hm, but what about passing a int& foo to an short& bar? All valid bar are valid foo values.

Comment: Then reading it (`short baz = bar`) will become invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there. You can use this if you want to accept **only** `buffer&` and `int`:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, buffer>::value>
setArgs(T &data, Args&&... params) {
    setArgs_<0, sizeof...(params), T, Args...>(data, std::forward<Args>(params)...);
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, int>::value>
setArgs(T data, Args&&... params) {
    setArgs_<0, sizeof...(params), T, Args...>(data, std::forward<Args>(params)...);
}
```

Or this if you plan to accept only lvalue references for both the types:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, buffer>::value or std::is_same<T, int>::value>
setArgs(T& data, Args&&... params) {
    setArgs_<0, sizeof...(params), T, Args...>(data, std::forward<Args>(params)...);
}
```

Or even this if you want to accept any kind of reference for both the types:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<std::decay_t<T>, buffer>::value or std::is_same<std::decay_t<T>, int>::value>
setArgs(T&& data, Args&&... params) {
    setArgs_<0, sizeof...(params), T, Args...>(std::forward<T>(data), std::forward<Args>(params)...);
}
```

In this case I would use forwarding references and `std::forward` through the rest of your class too, especially for the arguments.

Comment: whut, you can use or in templates like that? neat!

Comment: @dutt Yes, you can since the beginning. ;-)

Comment: I haven't really worked with writing slightly more advanced templates before, learning a lot :)

Comment: @dutt : `or` is just (IMO obnoxious) sugar for `||`, literally implemented as a macro in MSVC.

Answer (score 0):

You could also add a generic *setKernelArg* function that fails to compile with a `static_assert`:

```
template<int argNum, typename T>
void setKernelArg(T& data) {
            static_assert(sizeof(T) == 0, 
                          "Argument type not supported"); 
}
```

With this approach you can add other argument types later without getting an overly long *std::is_same* statement. This works also with c++11.

BTW: in your example code in line 7 you should probably pass *arg* instead of *numArg*.

Comment: But this will collapse if the second type just happens to have the same size of the class right?

Comment: What second type do you mean? There is only one type,  *T*,  in this template.